# ansible: run an nsis uninstaller silently

Tags: ansible, win-shell

A Windows application has been installed using an NSIS installer on a target machine under `C:\Program Files\my_app\`. In that folder there is also the uninstaller `Uninstall.exe`. I'm trying to write an ansible task that will run that uninstaller silently. The connection to that target machine is done using

```
ansible_connection: winrm
```

Running the following command **manually** on the target machine using a cmd prompt removes the application successfully and silently:

```
"C:\Program Files\my_app\Uninstall.exe" /S
```

However, when trying to implement my ansible task I cannot get it working. I've tried the following

```
  win_shell: '"C:\Program Files\my_app\Uninstall.exe" /S'
    args:
      executable: cmd
```

and

```
win_command: '"C:\Program Files\my_app\Uninstall.exe" /S'
```

Both of these tasks complete without an error, but the application is **not** uninstalled. This is the relevant output when running these tasks:

```
{
"start": "2021-11-13 08:37:57.146265",
"stdout": "",
"cmd": "\"C:\\Program Files\\my_app\\Uninstall.exe\" /S",
"stderr": "",
"changed": true,
"rc": 0,
"delta": "0:00:00.533985",
"end": "2021-11-13 08:37:57.680251",
"stdout_lines": [],
"stderr_lines": [],
"_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

What am I missing here? Many thanks

**EDIT**

The installer doesn't create an entry at the windows registry so using the ansible 'win_package' is not applicable as there is no 'product_id' I can use.

Answer (score 0):

i am using that to desinstall some packages:

```
- name: Uninstall my_app
  ansible.windows.win_package:
    path: C:\Program Files\my_app\Uninstall.exe
    product_id: my_app # -> to adapt 
    arguments: /S
    state: absent
```

you could even test without path:

```
- name: Uninstall my_app
  ansible.windows.win_package:
    product_id: my_app # -> to adapt 
    arguments: /S
    state: absent
```